# How to use puppet-apache mod (v8.3.0) with hiera?

Tags: puppet, apache2, hiera

**Queston**: Using the roles & profiles method, is it possible to use `'puppetlabs-apache', '8.3.0'` with a hiera lookup?

**Context**:

- I am using `mod 'puppetlabs-apache', '8.3.0'` to configure an apache server. I have a large number of apache re-write rules for various sites.
- Each site is configured hiera, e.g hiera.yaml:

  ```
   paths:
      - site/%{::site}.yaml
      - role/%{::role}.yaml
  ```
- where a webapp.pp role installs & configures `apache`
- it would be nice to lookup apache config in a site-dependent fashion, but can't find any documentation that helps

---

**Notes**

- I have found a similar question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/924082/q-how-to-define-apache-modules-via-puppet-and-hiera), but don't think that covers my particular use-case
- If hiera is unavailable for this module I could perform some logic in webapp.pp, e.g. something like this: `If ($facts['site'] == 'SITE-A') {outline rewrites for SITE-A}`
- however, this approach feels rather messy

Answer (score 0):

Ok so just in case anyone benefits, the solution was really straightforward and shows my puppet noob status.

**Solution**:

Looking at the [docs](https://forge.puppet.com/modules/puppetlabs/apache) you'll see the majority of data types are arrays, take the following example:

```
  apache::vhost { 'aliases.example.com':
      serveraliases => [
        'aliases.example.org',
        'aliases.example.net',
      ],
      port          => 80,
      docroot       => '/var/www/aliases',
    }
```

here `serveraliases` is an array. So you can simply lookup an array through hiera:

```
        class profiles::apache::secure_vhost(
            # Hiera lookup
            Array $site_serveraliases    = lookup('apache_site_serveraliases') )
            {
            apache::vhost { 'aliases.example.com':
            serveraliases => $site_serveraliases,
            port          => 80,
            docroot       => '/var/www/aliases',
            }
           )
```

Where $`apache_site_serveraliases` is a yaml array that varies between sites, e.g.:

```
apache_site_serveraliases:
  - paris.site.name
  - london.site.name
  - nyc.site.name
```

This way you can lookup apache_site_serveraliases in a site-dependent fashion.